# How to print pdf in 3 inch in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, printing

I am new in flutter Can I print pdf file directly to 3intch Bluetooth printer using dart. I tried to solve this using pdf package but in that only a5, a3, a4 like page sizes are available but I want to print in 3inch or 2 inch. Please give me any idea about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.roll80,
inside pdf.Page()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfPageFormat roll80 = PdfPageFormat(80 * PdfPageFormat.mm, 200 * PdfPageFormat.mm, marginAll: 5 * PdfPageFormat.mm);
PdfPageFormat roll57 = PdfPageFormat(57 * PdfPageFormat.mm, 200 * PdfPageFormat.mm, marginAll: 5 * PdfPageFormat.mm);

pdf.addPage(MultiPage(
    //pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.roll80,
      pageFormat:  roll80,
        build: (context) => [
        Text('invoice'),
        // your code here
      ],
    ));
```

There is a problem in the library PdfPageFormat :

```
 static const PdfPageFormat roll80 =
      PdfPageFormat(80 * mm, double.infinity, marginAll: 5 * mm);
```

**double.infinity** : This value is not predefined
Must be specified .